# How to hide a div using radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to hide the an entire field represented by a div id. I tried doing it, but it doesnt work. I could get it working when i used dropdown list and select. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p>
        <input type="radio" class="flat" name="botsign" id="signature" value="show" checked="checked"/>
        Show Signature
        <br><br>
        <input type="radio" class="flat" name="botsign" id="signature" value="hide" /> 
        Hide Signature
    </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $("input[name='botsign']").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'show') {
            $("#Sigbox").show();
        } else {
            $("#Sigbox").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
    #Sigbox{
       display:none;
      }
```

Comment: Your code works fine, try loading jQuery before your scripts.

Comment: I had some conflicting Javascripts. Once that is removed, it is working fine. Thank you @AdriánDaraš

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for helping me out. The code I posted does work fine, but there where some Javascript conflicts as I was using around 6 of them. I tried the above answers and even that didnt work, then I saw @AdriánDaraš comment and I cross checked with all the other Javascripts. And now its working fine as I removed the Javascript I was using to make the radio buttons look good.
Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 1):

*Try Like This*

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p>
        <input type="radio" class="flat" name="botsign" value="show" checked="checked"/> Show Signature<br><br>
        <input type="radio" class="flat" name="botsign" value="hide" /> Hide Signature
    </p>
</div> 


<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("input[name='botsign']").click(function() {
          if ($(this).val() == 'show') {
               $("#Sigbox").show();
           } else {
               $("#Sigbox").hide();
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add jquery from top of your head tag or bottom of file. And write jquery document ready for DOM ready, then you write your necessary code,that it

Answer (score 0):

Added the jquery cdn and a div box with an id to test the hide function. Then i used jQuery() that it's the normal way to call jquery.

The change function listen on both input and check the value of the input to know if must hide or show the box.

Here your solution:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>
                <input type="radio" 
                       class="flat" 
                       name="botsign" 
                       id="signature" 
                       value="show" 
                       checked="checked"/>
                Show Signature
                <br><br>
                <input type="radio" 
                       class="flat" 
                       name="botsign" 
                       id="signature" 
                       value="hide" />
                Hide Signature
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="Sigbox">
            hello i'm your sign box
        </div>
        <script>
            jQuery("input[name='botsign']").change(function () {
                if (jQuery(this).val() == 'show') {
                    jQuery("#Sigbox").show();
                } else {
                    jQuery("#Sigbox").hide();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```